# Describing contents of JWT token in OpenAPI

Tags: jwt, swagger, openapi

I am building a REST API that uses data in the JWT token to perform some operations. (E.g. verifying the ownership of the data, so for some cases, I might send `user_id` or something like that in the JWT token).

Is that possible to describe the expected contents of the JWT token using OpenAPI?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported as of OpenAPI 3.1, but there's an existing feature request:
[Allow payload definition for JWT schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1971)

Answer (score 0):

You can using JSON-schema, which is now compatible with OpenAPI 3.1:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "contentMediaType": "application/jwt",
    "contentSchema": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "prefixItems": [
            {
                "const": {
                    "typ": "JWT",
                    "alg": "HS256"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["iss", "exp"],
                "properties": {
                    "iss": {"type": "string"},
                    "exp": {"type": "integer"}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This example describes a JWT that is MACed using the HMAC SHA-256 algorithm, and requires the "iss" and "exp" fields in its claim set.

Ref: Example 3 from Section 8.6 of the [JSON Schema spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation#section-8.6)